# Check for null in JSON schema

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is it possible to validate null in a schema like [is property A is null then there will be some required field]

**For example:**

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"id": "college.json#",
"title": "student",
"description": "syidentdetails",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "colleges": {
        "type": "array"

    },
    "school": {
        "type": "array"
    },

    "if":{
        "properties":{
            "college":["type":null]
        }
    },"then":{["required":"school"]}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json nested Objects check if null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518549/json-nested-objects-check-if-null)

Comment: not in json nested Object ,have to check for null( or ) if the field is not found in the request in JSON schema

Comment: Confirming not a duplicate. This relates to JSON Schema. The other question does not.

Comment: Hi @sivaprakash - I think you may have a typo in your schema. The values of `properties` must be an object, not an array, and `"type": "null"` is fine, even for draft 4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your type value in quotes as opposed to actual just `null`.

`"type": "null"`